# Initializing a django modelform with data from url

Tags: django-forms

I have two models for store and city:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

If I have my Add Store url designed as

r^'mysite.com/city/(?[-\w]+)/venue/add$'

where the  represents the City.slug field can I initialize a StoreForm that automatically populates the Store.city field from the url data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, define your link as follows.

```
{%url somename relevant_slug_text%}
```

Or :

```
href='/mysite.com/city/{{slug_text}}/venue/add'
```

In your url conf, define your url like:

```
url(r^'mysite.com/city/(?P<slug_text>\w+)/venue/add$', 'func_name', name='somename')
```

So, you can pass the value of relelvant_slug_text variable to your url as slug_text, and in your function definiton:

```
def func_name(request, slug_text):
```

So , you can pass text value to your funcrtion with slug_text parameter...

EDIT: 
There are tow ways...

One:

Crete your city selection form using ModelForm..., then inthe second step, use posted data to populate your form again like:

```
form = StoreForm(request.POST)
```

then you can render this form to your template...

But if it is not possible o use this, yo ucan do the following...

Since you are using ModelForm to create your forms:

```
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your form field definitions are here
```

im your function, just override city field, but at this point, since you use modelform, your form thml will be created as

```
<select>
    <option value="id of record">"unicode value of record"</option>
```

So, you have record id's as option values. And you have slug_field values to initialize your field. So you have to get related city to use it...

```
my_city = City.objects.get(slug=<your_slug_value>)
```

Now you can override the form, but you must do it before you pass your form to a variable to render to your template...

```
StoreForm.base_fields['city'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), initial=my_city)
form = StoreForm()
```

Comment: How do I get the variable into the actual StoreForm instance? Can I initialize a StoreForm model with the city field populated via the url data and then get the rest of the info from an html form?